Error replying on WhatsApp Webhook: Message failed to send because more than 24 hours have passed since the customer last replied to this number
I am programming a webhook for the WhatsApp Cloud API. I am receiving user-initiated messages well, but when I send text messages replying to said messages, I am getting the following JSON from the WhatsApp API:
{
  "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": "MY_ID",
      "changes": [
        {
          "value": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "metadata": {
              "display_phone_number": "NUMBER",
              "phone_number_id": "PHONE"
            },
            "statuses": [
              {
                "id": "wamid.ENCRYPTED_CODE",
                "status": "failed",
                "timestamp": "TIMESTAMP",
                "recipient_id": "ID",
                "errors": [
                  {
                    "code": 131047,
                    "title": "Re-engagement message",
                    "message": "Re-engagement message",
                    "error_data": {
                      "details": "Message failed to send because more than 24 hours have passed since the customer last replied to this number."
                    },
                    "href": "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/support/error-codes/"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "field": "messages"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

My initial message was:
{
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "to": "MY_NUMBER",
  "text": {
    "body": "My message."
  },
  "type": "text"
}

I expected the message to be delivered, but instead I got the aforementioned error.

The error makes sense to me now: it happened because I changed my phone number from the test to a production one, but I forgot to update the WhatsApp ID in my code.
Essentially, I was receiving messages correctly but sending them from the old test number.
I updated the WhatsApp ID, and it works now. Thanks!

I had the same error during the development of the application (the application was still in development mode). What I did was register the recipient's number through the app's dashboard. In the 'API settings' section, where you select the development number, there is a 'from' field (where you select the development number) and a 'to' field (where you add the recipient). In the 'to' field, you can add new recipients (up to 5, if I'm not mistaken).
Just be aware that the removal and addition process takes 1 day (for example, when you remove a recipient, you can only remove another after 1 day; sending the default message templates also takes 1 day).

This is not an answer.
